# How to debug WeChat Browser in iPhone?

Tags: ios, html, wechat

I am having a hard time debugging development H5 pages for iPhone in WeChat browser.

I know that all browsers in iPhone are running some kind of Safari behind, but the one running under WeChat is so different from the native safari and it breaks a lot.

Methods tried:

- Tencent TBS_Studio ( Only works for Android )
- Safari Remove Debug ( Cannot detect pages opened in Wechat )
- Tencent Mini program console ( Only works for Android for real debug )

Currently I am total blind as I cannot get the console message. Could anyone advice? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Mac version of the debug tools?
https://open.wechat.com/cgi-bin/newreadtemplate?t=overseas_open/docs/oa/web/debug-tools

Comment: Thanks. This is the third option I listed above. It could only emulate but it cannot debug real iOS device.